# Почему выдает ошибку Attempt to read property "title" on null?

Tags: laravel

Почему мне выдает ошибку Attempt to read property "title" on null? Делаю список избранного. В бд товары добавляются, но я не могу их вывести на странице

```
public function index(){
        $user = Auth::user();
        $wishlist = Wish::where('user_id', $user->id)->orderby('id', 'desc')->get();
        return view('wish', compact('wishlist'));
    }
```

```
class Product extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    public function wishlist(){
        return $this->hasMany(Wish::class);
    }

}
```

```
public function wishlist(){
        return $this->hasMany(Wish::class);
    }
```

```
class Wish extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    protected $guarded = [];

    public function products(){
        return $this->belongsTo(Product::class);
    }
    public function user(){
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }
}
```

```
@foreach ($wishlist as $item)
{{$item->products->title}}
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 0):

Потому что Вы пытаетесь получить свойство `products`, а у какого-то из предметов в списке нет связи или вообще этого свойства не существует в ответе.

Для избежания ошибки нужно использовать optional chaining или проверять условием.

```
@foreach ($wishlist as $item)
    {{$item->products?->title}}
@endforeach
```

или

```
@foreach ($wishlist as $item)
    @if(!isset($item->products))
        {{$item->products->title}}
    @endif
@endforeach
```

---

Дальше не к основному вопросу.

Ошибка возникла (скорее всего, т.к Вы вероятнее всего указали везде предметы в базе) из-за того, что Вы не указываете связь в запросе. Само по себе связь вроде бы не подтягивает. Поэтому в `index` следующее должно быть:

```
$wishlist = Wish::where('user_id', $user->id)->with('products')->orderby('id', 'desc')->get();
```

И ещё смотрите внимательно, как обрабатываете данные в шаблоне. Вероятно, Вы ожидаете получить в `$item->products` массив, а не объект, поэтому в шаблоне должен быть второй цикл.

Comment: Все предметы в базе связаны, но ошибка все равно сохраняется

Comment: @Vladimir Читайте, что написано после черты. И дебагом выведите весь объект (`dd($wishlist);`), чтобы понять, что Вы в шаблон получаете

Comment: `$wishlist` выводит запись из базы wishlist, где указан пользователь и товар. А $wishlist->products выводит null

Comment: Проблема была в отношениях